# Getting "Invalid address" error in Shopping cart of Ubercart

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, ubercart

We are getting following error when we enter an email address which is not already present in the system:

"Sending of atleast one email failed. The error returned was: Invalid address"

Any idea where should we check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Drupal's "Watchdog" log under **Admin > Reports > Recent log entries** for more details on the error.